# How can I prevent an async method from being reentrant?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, async-await

I have an async method in my program. I need the task to be asynchronous because it makes network requests, but I don't want it to be reentrant. In other words, if the method is called from code block A, and then again from code block B before the first invocation returns, I want the second invocation to wait until the first invocation finishes before it runs.

If the method were not an async method, I'd be able to accomplish it with this annotation:
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]

However, the compiler does not allow the annotation to be attached to an async method.

What else can I do?

Comment: You can e. g. use something like `SemaphoreSlim` to only let one thread at a time enter the method.

Comment: `Synchronized` is just an implicit `lock`, and while you can't `lock` in an `async` method, there do exist things like `SemaphoreSlim` and [`AsyncLock`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncLock) to achieve mutual exclusion in an async way. As an aside, consider not using `Synchronized` even in sync code -- it's basically there because Java has it, but the implicit `lock (this)` it does is a much worse idea than locking on a private field explicitly declared for that purpose.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=netframework-4.8), which is a lock with a [`WaitAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.waitasync?view=netframework-4.8) method on it (and which doesn't mind you releasing it on a different thread to the one you acquired it on).

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim methodLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

public async Task SomeMethod()
{
    await methodLock.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    finally
    {
        methodLock.Release();
    }
}
```

If you're feeling adventurous, you can write an extension method on `SemaphoreSlim`, letting you do e.g.:

```
public async Task SomeMethod()
{
    using (await methodLock.WaitDisposableAsync())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Be careful though: `SemaphoreSlim` is **not recursive** (nor can it be). That means if your method is recursive, it will deadlock.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the reply. I'll give this a try, sounds like what I need.